# React component errors out

Tags: reactjs, jsx, yarnpkg

Im trying to create a component using React. I have finished code, but when running "yarn run bundle", the code errors out here and i receive the error code

"Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (9:10)"

Below is where I am getting an error. Can anybody think of why?

```
export class NewBond extends React.Component {
    state = {name:''};


Package.json
{
 "name": "react-app",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node --use_strict index.js",
 "dev": "nodemon --use_strict index.js",
 "bundle": "webpack"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.16.1",
  "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
  "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
  "express": "^4.15.3",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.1",
  "material-ui": "^0.18.1",
  "mongoose": "^4.10.4",
  "passport": "^0.3.2",
  "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
  "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
  "react": "^15.5.4",
  "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
  "react-router": "^4.1.1",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
  "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
  "semantic-ui-react": "^0.78.3",
  "validator": "^7.0.0",
  "yarn": "^1.5.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
  "webpack": "^2.6.1"
 }
```

}

Comment: not enough code

Comment: Can you share your package.json

Comment: Please show the full code

Comment: My raw guess is that it has to do with the _export_ token. Do you compile your code with e.g. babel?

Comment: are you using create-react-app ? if not, do you have the class-properties babel plugin?

Comment: @Aaqib Posted above

Comment: @Hysi probably you need `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` ? https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Comment: @KevinQian Nope that doesnt seem to fix it. If it helps the error points to the =   in state = {name:''};